# PHP Header ISSUE, location redirects to home (PHP 5.5)

Tags: php, redirect, header

In my localhost (PHP 5.5) sometimes when I make a

`header("Location: /mydestiny.php")`

redirect, the script redirects to home /

On my server (PHP 5.3) this don´t happen.

Somebody has any idea why this could be happening?

Thanks!

Comment: can you check witht the alphabet case of filename

Comment: I never use special chars. Here an example of redirect
header("Location: /vehicles/booking.php?item=".$result."&new");